# Mac OS X 10.7 default postgres with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql

Is the default version of postgres, that ships with OS X Lion suitable for use on my local machine while developing Ruby on Rails applications?

I'm reading about people installing postgres from brew or macports and running another version that the default. There doesn't seem to be an obvious reason.

Comment: IIRC only the client is locally installed (unless you are on the server version).

Comment: It's suitable. The reason you've been reading about people installing it is that PostgreSQL wasn't bundled with OS X until version 10.7 (Lion), which has only been out for a few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suitable unless you want to use advanced features on new versions.  Thats the only trade-off.

In general I recommend working on the oldest widely used/supported versions (right now being 9.1 and 8.4) if you want to publish your application.